# How to determine the number of lines being used in UILabel (Swift)?

Tags: swift, uilabel, xcode7, sizetofit

```
cell.bodyText.numberOfLines = 0

cell.bodyText.text = newsBody
cell.bodyText.sizeToFit()
```

I set the number of lines to 0 because the number of lines can vary (I am retrieving news articles and since every news article is obviously different in length, numberOfLines is 0)

If I do not use `sizeToFit()` after assinging `newsBody` to the label, and check the label height (`cell.bodyText.frame.size.height)`, I get really large numbers (when I tested it, an article that had 25 lines of text, the height was apparently 4000). If I use `sizeToFit`and then check the height, I get 21 no matter how short or long the label is. (21 is the height I set the UILabel in the storyboard).

How can I get an accurate representation of how many lines are in the UILabel or even just the height of the label?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're doing this work in `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`. That's not reliable for querying final layout. Try using the delegate method `tableView(_:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)`. That's called immediately before displaying the cell, and is the appropriate place to work out any final layout issues since everything has been applied at that point.

Comment: That still doesn't solve my problem though. I'm still getting the exact same numbers

Comment: In `willDisplayCell`,  `cell.bodyText.frame.size` doesn't match the size you see on the screen?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have no idea what's going on. I've never had this problem before

Comment: That is strange. I haven't done a lot of size querying in autolayout cells, and maybe that gets applied later, but could have sworn it was applied prior to `willDisplayCell`. (I assume this is autolayout?)

Comment: You can always work out the text size by hand (see `NSAttributedString.boundingRectWithSize(:options:context:)`, or the similar method for `NSString`). But it's a bit of a pain to get it to match the `UILabel` exactly. I don't know beyond that.

Comment: I have different problem but the logic helps me to resolve my problem (use viewdidappear instead of viewdidload)